# Any web services available for item level permission in sharepoint?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, permissions

Through web services i am trying to set the user permission to the document inside the document library.

Is there any web services available to set the (Read/Full Control/Contribute) to the document in share point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, an OOTB web service to apply fine grained permissions does not exist. The best that can be done, is to the site or list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcpermissions.permissions.addpermission.aspx

You should be able to create a web service to do it though, here is an example:

http://www.codefornuts.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html

Comment: http://www.codefornuts.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html        This site don't have the web service file.. i tried to download it it it give the 404 error