# Define permissions to a file through SharePoint web service

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is there a web service (out of the box) in SharePoint that allows to define permissions to a file in SharePoint ?

We are looking at developing an interface (for example in Java) by invoking out of the box SharePoint web service to define user groups who have access and who does not have access to a file based on the URL of the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Any web services available for item level permission in sharepoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861010/any-web-services-available-for-item-level-permission-in-sharepoint/4861773#4861773)